# Checkbox inside popover not working

Tags: ionic-framework

I have this [Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPRpLr) here i have added a check box in popover. The added check box is not responding to any event neither model is set on checkbox selection.

```
        <li class="item item-checkbox">
           <label class="checkbox">
             <input type="checkbox" name="isAnonymous" ng-change="setAnonymous(this)" ng-model="isAnonymous"/>
           </label>Post as anonymous
        </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

A breaking change was introduced into UIWebView for iOS 9. Other platforms should work just fine.

[iOS 9 Potential Breaking Change](http://blog.ionic.io/ios-9-potential-breaking-change/)

[Preparing for iOS 9](http://blog.ionic.io/preparing-for-ios-9/)

Comment: i am using in android